# Westend PartialFees in version 9190

Tags: fee, westend

Does the 9190 version of westend change something with fees? We used to parse a transaction and check for a field called partialFee but looks like it's not present anymore since I see this for a block now instead:

"info":{"error":"Fee calculation not supported for 9190#westend"}

On latest substrate/polkadot versions.

Polkadot v0.9.18
substrate-api-sidecar v11.3.16

Comment: The partialFee seems to be defined in the sidecar project: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So for sidecar specifically this is a bug due to `TransactionByteFee` being changed to `LengthToFee` in v9190. We use that perByte value to help calculate the `partialFee` within our helper package called `@substrate/calc`.

See the following PR which introduced these changes inside of polkadot: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/pull/5028

See the following PR that fixes this issue inside of substrate-api-sidecar: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar/pull/900

As soon as that PR is merged a new patch release will be shipped, there is a tracking issue in github here: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar/issues/899